# How to create an interactive loading page by embedding in the Wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, custom-wordpress-pages

I have seen the tutorials for creating a loading page using CSS and Javascript and their implementation.But in my wordpress theme,I have no such file as "index.html" visible in the editor section of Dashboard.All files are in PHP.Please help.

Comment: Did you have a index.php?

Comment: Need to read up on how wordpress themes work and how to extend them using child themes